# Java Regex Pattern for URL list on JSON format

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm having some trouble finding the correct regex for what I need to match.

The source code looks like this:

```
\"url240\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.240.mp4?extra=hash\"
,\"url360\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.360.mp4?extra=hash\"
,\"url480\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.480.mp4?extra=hash\"
,\"url720\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.720.mp4?extra=hash\"
```

I need to match all urls (can be one, two, three or all four, it depends on the source code provided to the app) and store them on an ArrayList.

This is the code I normally use:

```
List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern vPattern = Pattern.compile(?);
Matcher videoMatcher = vPattern.matcher(source);
while (videoMatcher.find())
    sourceList.add(videoMatcher.group(2));
```

But the pattern I normally use can't be used in this scenario.

I tried with:

```
\\"url\d+\\":\\"(.*?)\\"
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the source you listed your expression is correct. The problem has to do with string escaping.

When using the expression in Java we are parsing the string twice before we use it, first when the Java string is created and once more by the regular expression engine, what you are matching is `\"url[0-9]+\":\"(.*?)\"`, you have done the first level of escaping (for the regex engine). Next we need to escape the string again for Java.

So in order to get the expression you posted, we need to escape all `\`'s so that they become `\` in the final string and is not processed as an escape sequence by Java, and we need to escape `"`'s since the whole thing is one string and unescaped `"` terminates the string.

This means we need to prefix all `\`'s and `"`'s with a `\`, this can easily be done using search and replace in any editor as long as we replace `\` with `\\` before `"` with `\"` as we don't want to escape the `\`'s added when we escape `"`.

This gives us: `"\\\\\"url\\d+\\\\\":\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\""`.

Other than that, the expression only has one matching group, so we need to get `videoMatcher.group(1)` not `videoMatcher.group(2)`.

**Test-code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "\\\"url240\\\":\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/domain.com\\\\\\/id123456\\\\\\/files\\\\\\/video.240.mp4?extra=hash\\\",\n\\\"url360\\\":\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/domain.com\\\\\\/id123456\\\\\\/files\\\\\\/video.360.mp4?extra=hash\\\",\n\\\"url480\\\":\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/domain.com\\\\\\/id123456\\\\\\/files\\\\\\/video.480.mp4?extra=hash\\\",\n\\\"url720\\\":\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/domain.com\\\\\\/id123456\\\\\\/files\\\\\\/video.720.mp4?extra=hash\\\"";
    String pattern = "\\\\\"url\\d+\\\\\":\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"";

    System.out.println("Source: " + source);
    System.out.println("\nPattern: " + pattern);

    List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern vPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher videoMatcher = vPattern.matcher(source);
    while (videoMatcher.find()) {
        sourceList.add(videoMatcher.group(1));
    }

    System.out.println("\nResult:" + Arrays.toString(sourceList.toArray(new String[0])));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Source: \"url240\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.240.mp4?extra=hash\",
\"url360\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.360.mp4?extra=hash\",
\"url480\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.480.mp4?extra=hash\",
\"url720\":\"https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.720.mp4?extra=hash\"

Pattern: \\"url\d+\\":\\"(.*?)\\"

Result:[https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.240.mp4?extra=hash, https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.360.mp4?extra=hash, https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.480.mp4?extra=hash,     https:\\\/\\\/domain.com\\\/id123456\\\/files\\\/video.720.mp4?extra=hash]
```

As we can see, the value of the pattern string, once it has been un-escaped once is the regular expression we wanted.

Comment: Thank you!, I figure it out yesterday but your answer is correct.